# pyenv virtualenv activation not work when use full path

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I install `pyenv` on centos, and check if its working.

```
# curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
104  2099  104  2099    0     0  14121      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 18575
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/.pyenv/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 4531, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1831/1831), done.
remote: Total 4531 (delta 3252), reused 3506 (delta 2419), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (4531/4531), 1019.80 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3252/3252), done.
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-doctor/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 18, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 5), reused 14 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-installer/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 22, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 22 (delta 4), reused 13 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-update/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 1), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 478, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (309/309), done.
remote: Total 478 (delta 313), reused 271 (delta 144), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (478/478), 259.55 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (313/313), done.
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-which-ext/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 20, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 20 (delta 2), reused 14 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (20/20), done.

WARNING: seems you still have not added 'pyenv' to the load path.

# Load pyenv automatically by adding
# the following to ~/.bash_profile:

export PATH="/root/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
[root@localhost ~]# export PATH="/root/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
[root@localhost ~]# eval "$(pyenv init -)"
[root@localhost ~]# eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# pyenv
pyenv 1.2.1
Usage: pyenv <command> [<args>]

Some useful pyenv commands are:
   commands    List all available pyenv commands
   local       Set or show the local application-specific Python version
   global      Set or show the global Python version
   shell       Set or show the shell-specific Python version
   install     Install a Python version using python-build
   uninstall   Uninstall a specific Python version
   rehash      Rehash pyenv shims (run this after installing executables)
   version     Show the current Python version and its origin
   versions    List all Python versions available to pyenv
   which       Display the full path to an executable
   whence      List all Python versions that contain the given executable

See `pyenv help <command>' for information on a specific command.
For full documentation, see: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#readme
```

Installed new version python.

```
# pyenv install 2.7.13
Downloading Python-2.7.13.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tar.xz
Installing Python-2.7.13...
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
WARNING: The Python bz2 extension was not compiled. Missing the bzip2 lib?
WARNING: The Python sqlite3 extension was not compiled. Missing the SQLite3 lib?
Installed Python-2.7.13 to /root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13
```

Create virtualenv.

```
# pyenv virtualenv 2.7.13 myenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-15.1.0
New python executable in /root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myenv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

When activate `myenv` its working fine.

```
# pyenv activate myenv
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior.
(myenv) [root@localhost ~]# source deactivate
pyenv-virtualenv: deactivate 2.7.13/envs/myenv
```

When I use full path, then it gives error.

```
[root@localhost ~]# which pyenv
/root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv
[root@localhost ~]# /root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv activate myenv

Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.
```

I can use `pyenv` for my testing, but when I have to use `pyenv` in `ansible`, I have to give full path as `/root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using pyenv you need to reference the version that you are wanting to run. Try something like this:

```
/root/.pyenv/versions/myenv/bin/python
```

That is assuming your `PYENV_ROOT` environment variable is set to `/root/.pyenv/`

When you execute python this way it is like activating the virtualenv, grabbing any installed libraries you had in the virtualenv as well.

Starting a fresh environment:

```
host:~ user$ pyenv virtualenv 2.7.12 myenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.8MB 744kB/s
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-15.1.0
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
New python executable in /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/envs/myenv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/envs/myenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pip in /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Activate the virtual environment and show that requests is not installed by default. Install it.

```
host:~$ pyenv activate myenv
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior.
(myenv) host:~ $ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec 15 2016, 12:49:19)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
>>>
(myenv) host:~$ pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Downloading requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 2.0MB/s
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 4.0MB/s
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Downloading certifi-2017.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (330kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 337kB 3.0MB/s
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Downloading urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 5.8MB/s
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Downloading idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 7.0MB/s
Installing collected packages: chardet, certifi, urllib3, idna, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2017.11.5 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.6 requests-2.18.4 urllib3-1.22
```

Show that it is now installed in the virtual env:

```
(myenv) host:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec 15 2016, 12:49:19)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>>
```

Deactivate and show that the default python is a different version:

```
(myenv) host:~$ pyenv deactivate
host:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 21 2016, 15:26:09)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Run the `myenv` virtualenv directly

```
host:~$ ~/.pyenv/versions/myenv/bin/python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec 15 2016, 12:49:19)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>>
```

Comment: can you send me how to use this? I tried `/root/.pyenv/versions/myenv/bin/python activate myenv` but it failed.

Comment: You don't actually activate the environment with that command. That will run the python command within the scope of that environment. Including all the packages you have installed in it. So `/root/.pyenv/versions/myenv/bin/python` will actually run python from you `myenv` virtualenv.

Comment: That I get, only problem is, with ansible `command` module, I am not able to use `pyenv`, have to use `/root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv` and that is not working with activate.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding what it is you are trying to accomplish in ansible. Maybe you can update your OP with what it is you have in ansible.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but want to know that, if `pyenv` is pointing to `/root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv` then `pyenv activate myenv` works fine, but when use full path as `/root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv activate myenv` not works, what change in that ?