# Pyenv Python versions not working in Linux Shell scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create shell script on Linux (Ubuntu) as presented in [Automate the boring stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/appendixb/#calibre_link-683)

I've created all the files and Python script and when I'm trying to run it from Dash in Ubuntu it runs Python script with Python version that is not in my pyenv global version. Because of that i can't use any additional modules installed via pip.

My Python versions (as listed with pyenv versions)

```
  system
* 3.8.1 (set by /home/tomek/.python-version)
  3.8.1/envs/blog_env
  3.8.1/envs/ll_env
  3.8.1/envs/mcam_env
  3.8.1/envs/money_value
  3.8.1/envs/pizzaenv
  3.8.1/envs/project_2
  blog_env
  ll_env
  mcam_env
  money_value
  pizzaenv
  project_2
```

version 3.8.1 is set as global with pyenv. Some details:

```
which python && which pip && python -V
/home/tomek/.pyenv/shims/python
/home/tomek/.pyenv/shims/pip
Python 3.8.1
```

My .sh (placed in my home directory) file looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python3 /home/tomek/automate/MCAM/mClip.py 'agree'
bash
```

My .desktop file (placed in .local/share/applications
 needed to run script via Dash in Ubuntu) looks like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=mClip
Exec=gnome-terminal -- /home/tomek/mClip.sh
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Utility;
```

and my first line in Python script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

So, when i run my script from shell it works fine, but when i run it via Dash it gets error because of missing modules, so it's trying to run it with different Python environment.
I tried to debug this script the same way i tried to run it so i changed .sh file this way

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
which python && which pip && python -V && python3 -V
bash
```

and i get this result

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/pip
Python 2.7.17
Python 3.6.9
```

When i then run this code in same shell window (!) it gives me

```
/home/tomek/.pyenv/shims/python
/home/tomek/.pyenv/shims/pip
Python 3.8.1
Python 3.8.1
```

I've tried also to run pyenv in this .sh script to see whats the outcome but it gives me error that pyenv command is not found.
I've tried to look everywhere for some answers but not a single one worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out answer for my own question.

Installing and configuring pyenv as user will not make it work for sh files ran from Ubuntu Dash.
When you configure pyenv you configure bash configuration files (like .bashrc).

> This configuration files are only loaded when you start bash, not when you run some other program such as sh (not even if bash is invoked via the name sh). And it's only loaded when bash is interactive.

You have to run virtual environment directly like this (this is for default pyenv install location).

For example, checking python version:

```
/home/<username>/.pyenv/versions/<environment_name>/bin/python -V
```

Going back to my case. My sh file looks like this now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python -V
/home/tomek/.pyenv/versions/mcam_env/bin/python -V
bash
```

and the result is

```
Python 2.7.17 #This is default Python version for root
Python 3.8.1 #This is my pyenv Python version
```

Futher reading:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48288532/13105480
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228441/401700

Answer (score 0):

In your Python script your first line says `#!/usr/bin/env python`, so I think this redirects to `/usr/bin/python`, which is the wrong one. Could you try `#!/usr/bin/env python3`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This way i run script with Python3 (actually version Python 3.6.9) but it's not version of Python that I have installed globally with Pyenv. It's some system version of Python whithout any pip modules.

Comment: So your python Version is 2.7?

Comment: My global python version set with pyenv is 3.8.1 but when i run script via method I described it's 2.7.17 or 3.6.9.